# Evento on(change) em radio button

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

No projeto tenho um arquivo que faz consultas de preços de frete e que ao mesmo tempo retorna dois radio buttons com os valores de frete. Sendo o retorno do HTML da seguinte forma:

```
<p>
    <b>Selecione: </b><br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipocep" value="1;40.50" class="seltipocep">
    PAC <b>R$ 40,50</b> prazo de 28 dia(s)<br> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipocep" value="2;129.40" class="seltipocep">
    SEDEX <b>R$129,40</b> prazo de 4 dia(s)
    <input type="hidden" name="addfrete" value="1"></p>
```

Esse conteúdo HTML é retornado através da seguinte requisição AJAX:

```
$("form#consultafrete").submit(function(event) {
    /* Act on the event */
    event.preventDefault();

    <?php if($pagina == 'carrinho'){ ?>
    var tipoCEP = 100;
    <?php }else{ ?>
    var tipoCEP = '';
    <?php } ?>

    var totalItens = <?php echo $_SESSION['carrinho']['total_itens'] ?>;
    var $legendacep = $("#legendacep");
    var meucepCalc = $("#seucep").val();

    if(meucepCalc != ''){

        $legendacep.html("Carregando...");

        $.post(
            '<?=$siteUrl?>/calcula-frete.php',
            { meucep: meucepCalc, tipo_saida: tipoCEP, qtd: totalItens },
            function(data) {
                var resultado = '<p>'+data+'</p>';                      
                $legendacep.html(resultado);                        
            });
        }
    });
```

O que eu pretendo fazer é que quando o retorno possuir radio buttons, ao selecionar um deles, eu possa efetuar alguma ação, já tentei de várias formas mas não funciona. O fato de não funcionar é porque o conteúdo é dinâmico? Uma das formas que tentei:

```
$("input[name=tipocep]").change(function() {                
                alert("sDSDS");
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim o problema é de delegação pois esse conteúdo foi adicionado depois do JS ter sido lido.

Podes delegar o evento num parente, por exemplo: `#legendacep`.

```
$("#legendacep").on('change', "input[name=tipocep]", function() {                
    alert("sDSDS");
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/0xdtg3gx/

Comment: Perfeito @Sergio, funcionando certinho. Obrigado.